# How to make triangle prime numbers in php

Tags: php, html, loops

I have a problem with my php script, I want to make a prime numbers in triangle but I have some error.

**php**

```
<?php
    for($a=0;$a<=3;$a++) {
        for($b=$a;$b>=0;$b--) {
            for($i=1;$i<=20;$i++) {
                $counter = 0;
                for($j=1;$j<=$i;$j++) {
                    if($i%$j==0) {
                        $counter++;
                    }
                }   
                if($counter==2) {
                    print $i;
                }
            }
        }
        echo "<br />";
    }
?>
```

**output**

```
235711131719
235711131719235711131719
235711131719235711131719235711131719
235711131719235711131719235711131719235711131719
```

**what I want output**

```
     2
    3 3
   5 5 5
    3 3
     2
```

I don't know what is wrong. thank you before

Comment: A sample Correct Output (which you want) might help

Comment: According to this : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1012320/how-many-prime-numbers-are-also-triangular-numbers maybe you can do it this way : 1/ You make an algo to find all prime number 2/ You test if this prime number is triangular

Comment: @MittulAtTechnoBrave no its not

Comment: @ImamNur Just to be sure, you want to make triangular prime number or something else? Can you edit you question and add what you get with this + what is the desired output?

Comment: @ImamNur what's the desired output?

Comment: I dont know how you guys are related. same type of question in 3-4 days https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49606094/how-to-create-a-list-of-prime-numbers-in-a-right-angle-triangle and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49569741/how-do-i-display-the-prime-numbers-in-reverse-triangle

Comment: check the update

Comment: @smarber check my new update